# Fixing uneven chest size

Tags: weightlifting, chest

So I've been working out pretty consistently for the past two years, and I've always had much more volume in my left pectoral than my right. Is there a convenient way for me to correct this? My weight training involving my chest primarily are bench press and flyes. To give some background, I typically find myself doing more reps with lower weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!

Uneven or uneven pectorals are a common phenomenon among people who train. There are two types of unequal pectorals. First there are those who are different, that is: it is not that it is a bigger or literally massive, only that they look different. This problem is caused simply by genetics. The chest sticks to the sternum (the bone behind it). And in several cases, it does not stick at all in the same way. Since the sternum is not a flat bone, your pectorals can stick differently to it, and it is a very common case.

The second type of unequal pectoral is the case in which one has more muscle mass than in another. This is much less for genetics and more for the activities we do every day. If in your work or your hobbie, etc. you use more of your right arm than the left one, little by little you are indirectly stimulating the pectoral, and if your food is healthy and the stimulation is significant, it could generate unequal growth.

**How to fix it?**

If your case is the first, unfortunately there is no objection. It is something that would be difficult to do even with a surgical operation. If your case is the second, we have a solution. To begin the first step would be to stop doing bench press. When performing a bench press with one pectoral larger than the other, you are letting the smaller one cheat by carrying less weight. It happens to make dumbbells, each arm will have independence of by itself and will be stimulated without external help.

An extra could be performing bench press with unilateral dumbbell. In this way you will concentrate 100% on the pectoral that you need to stimulate.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a convenient way to determine which case pertains to me?

Comment: Sure, you mentioned in your question that you've always had one pectoral bigger than another,
 So if before you started some physical activity a pectoral was bigger than the other, it is more likely that your "problem" is genetic.
If your pectorals were the same size before starting physical activity, the problem is in your physical activities.
Also you could consult a doctor.